# ficus configuration load generic

Tags: scala, class-hierarchy, classtag

Loading a ficus configuration like

```
loadConfiguration[T <: Product](): T = {
import net.ceedubs.ficus.readers.ArbitraryTypeReader._
import net.ceedubs.ficus.Ficus._
val config: Config = ConfigFactory.load()
config.as[T]
```

fails with:

```
Cannot generate a config value reader for type T, because it has no apply method in a companion object that returns type T, and it doesn't have a primary constructor
```

when instead directly specifying a case class instead of `T` i.e. `SomeClass` it works just fine. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ficus uses the [type class pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_class), which allows you to constrain generic types by specifying operations that must be available for them. Ficus also provides type class instance "derivation", which in this case is powered by a macro that can inspect the structure of a specific case class-like type and automatically create a type class instance.

The problem in this case is that `T` isn't a specific case class-like type—it's any old type that extends `Product`, which could be something nice like this:

```
case class EasyToDecode(a: String, b: String, c: String)
```

But it could also be:

```
trait X extends Product {
  val youWillNeverDecodeMe: String
}
```

The macro you've imported from `ArbitraryTypeReader` has no idea at this point, since `T` is generic here. So you'll need a different approach.

The relevant type class here is `ValueReader`, and you could minimally change your code to something like the following to make sure `T` has a `ValueReader` instance (note that the `T: ValueReader` syntax here is what's called a "context bound"):

```
import net.ceedubs.ficus.Ficus._
import net.ceedubs.ficus.readers.ValueReader
import com.typesafe.config.{ Config, ConfigFactory }

def loadConfiguration[T: ValueReader]: T = {
  val config: Config = ConfigFactory.load()
  config.as[T]

}
```

This specifies that `T` must have a `ValueReader` instance (which allows us to use `.as[T]`) but says nothing else about `T`, or about where its `ValueReader` instance needs to come from.

The person calling this method with a concrete type `MyType` then has several options. Ficus provides instances that are automatically available everywhere for many standard library types, so if `MyType` is e.g. `Int`, they're all set:

```
scala> ValueReader[Int]
res0: net.ceedubs.ficus.readers.ValueReader[Int] = net.ceedubs.ficus.readers.AnyValReaders$$anon$2@6fb00268
```

If `MyType` is a custom type, then either they can manually define their own `ValueReader[MyType]` instance, or they can import one that someone else has defined, or they can use generic derivation (which is what `ArbitraryTypeReader` does).

The key point here is that the type class pattern allows you as the author of a generic method to specify the operations you need, without saying anything about how those operations will be defined for a concrete type. You just write `T: ValueReader`, and your caller imports `ArbitraryTypeReader` as needed.

Comment: So I would need to create an implicit value reader? As currently, I get: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type net.ceedubs.ficus.readers.ValueReader - even adding `def loadConfiguration[T: ValueReader](implicit reader: ArbitraryTypeReader): T = {` does not fix it. Also importing `import net.ceedubs.ficus.readers.ArbitraryTypeReader._` for the caller will not yet resolve the problem.

Comment: No, you definitely don't need (or want) the implicit `ArbitraryTypeReader`, just the `ValueReader`. Given the definitions above, you can just import `ArbitraryTypeReader._` (at the use site, not where you're defining `loadConfiguration`) and call `loadConfiguration[EasyToDecode]`.

Comment: I try to follow your instructions - but it does not seem to work yet. `ArbitraryTypeReader._` is imported on the caller sided i.e. `loadConfiguration[SomeCaseClass]` and the method looks just like you suggested, however, the error of: `Cannot generate a config ...` remains. Trying a `implicit val valueReader = ValueReader[HashingConfiguration]` fails.

Comment: @GeorgHeiler By "doesn't work" what do you mean? Does a simple case class (like the one in the answer) compile?

Comment: Same error for `EasyToDecode` or my own case class.

Comment: That's odd then—`loadConfiguration[EasyToDecode]` compiles just fine for me (which is what I'd expect). You're importing both `Ficus._` and `ArbitraryTypeReader._`?

Comment: Classes look like this: https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/a71c87bac767cba859faf817fca5315e if you do not spot the problem I can sin up a sample project on GitHub in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Actually, the error also specifies: `Cannot generate a config value reader for type String, because it has no apply method in a companion object that returns type String, and it doesn't have a primary constructor` - it feels a bit strange that ** String** would not be supported ...

Comment: `import net.ceedubs.ficus.Ficus._` - this also should be imported even if it marked as unsed by IDE